# Doxygen: Modules page content

Tags: doxygen

In doxygen, if you create modules, the modules page will show up, with very basic content:

[image: Doxygen Modules]

I would like to customize this page by added some description how the modules are related.

First thing I tried was to simply reference the "modules" page:

```
/*!
@page modules

Can you see this content?

@details This is some extra content!

@section Detail-Section
Show yourself!
*/
```

This adds a link to normal modules page in "related pages", but the things I enter there will still not show up. In fact, they seem to be completly ignored!

I was not able to find out where to add this content, but checking the genereated html file let's me assume that it is possible.

The following snippet shows the html code that comes after the table that lists the modules:

```
</table>
</div><!-- directory -->
</div><!-- contents -->
<!-- start footer part -->
```

So, is there a way to actually add "contents" with doxygen from a comment like for normal custom pages?

Comment: This is an excellent question! Have you found a way to put custom content onto the Modules page? What is the correct way to link to the Modules page? Thanks!

Comment: No, I did not find a "good" way. What I did was to create a custom html part, and manually edit the modules html after the creation to add the contents. It's ugly, but it seems to be the only way

Comment: Yes, if you want to significantly customize the doxygen output, then it seems as if you have to resort to something like that or use [breathe](http://breathe.readthedocs.org/) (or something similar) that builds on top of the doxygen xml output.